# To sync before shapshot or not to sync?

Tags: btrfs

There is a Postgres database on BTRFS. I need to make a backup of the database while it is running. Should I do `btrfs filesystem sync` before the snapshot or `btrfs subvolume snapshot` does it for me automatically?

Comment: what speaks against a mysql dump?

Comment: @djdomi It being postgresql?

Comment: The database identifies itself as PostgreSQL, there is little I can do.

Comment: Don't forget to properly prepare the database before creating a snapshot: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/319538/postgresql-backup-with-zfs-snapshots-is-pg-start-backup-pg-stop-backup-nece

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`btrfs-subvolume`](https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/btrfs-subvolume.html) man page:

> Subvolume creation needs to flush dirty data that belong to the subvolume

So yes, `btrfs subvolume snapshot` will take care of it for you if we stick to your question.

Given that you're attempting to backup a PostgreSQL database, depending on the scenario you might also be interested in the `pg_dump` utility instead or PostgreSQL WAL-shipping if you need point-in-time recovery.

Comment: I am moving away from pg_dump as it takes too long to restore a large database.